# Add tabBarController item in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have program which use an API to collect the schedule list of different TV channels, I have maybe 10 TV channels so I don't want to add manually the 10 items in my tabBar controller

I use this code to collect my channels :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://apis.is/tv"];
    // Download JSON
    NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    // Parse JSON
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:JSONData //1

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];
    NSArray* jsonResult = [json objectForKey:@"channels"];
    _channelList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (id item in jsonResult) {
        TVShow *TVChannel = [[TVShow alloc] init];
        TVChannel.channel = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
        TVChannel.endpoint = [item objectForKey:@"endpoint"];
        [_channelList addObject:TVChannel];
    }
}
```

I wanted to know how with that I can add a tap bar item for each channel

Thanks guys

Comment: not possible to add more than five tab item in tabbar controller. Another option is that to create custom scrollable tabbar where you can add as many as tabs as you want.

Comment: When there is more than 5 items , they are automatically  put in a "more" item no ?

Comment: yes, they will be automatically added into more tab in tableview format.

Comment: So do you know how i can put an in item by the code and not by the storyboard ?

Comment: sorry I could not get you. Could you please explain?

Comment: I want to obtain from my API the name of the channel and then create a tab bar item with the name of the channel which will link to the table view which displays the schedule list of this selected channel

Comment: yes, but for your case I would suggest first create 5 tab bar items in storybaord. 5th tab bar item would have 'more' action. On clicking of 'more' you have to show all remaining items. 

For showing items from 5tb tabbar table, create a UIViewController & display item/moview from table item selection. 
If you are looking for a scrollable tab bar then you have to get custom lib from GIT/Cocoacotrls

Comment: Check my answer, hope it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working fine for me... You can just copy and paste it... :)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://apis.is/tv"];
// Download JSON
NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
// Parse JSON
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:JSONData //1

                      options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                      error:&error];
NSArray* jsonResult = json[@"results"][0][@"channels"];
_channelList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (id item in jsonResult) {
    TVShow *TVChannel = [[TVShow alloc] init];
    TVChannel.channel = item[@"name"];
    TVChannel.endpoint = item[@"endpoint"];
    [_channelList addObject:TVChannel];
}


NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSInteger tabTag = 0;
for (TVShow *show in self.channelList) {
    ViewController1 *view1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:view1];
    view1.mainLabel.text = show.channel;
    view1.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:show.channel
                                                     image:nil
                                                       tag:tabTag];
    tabTag++;
}
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:tabViewControllers];
[self.window setRootViewController: tabBarController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```